# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header present Rails with Rack CORS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I am making a request to the Google Maps API within my app. I am currently running a development version locally. I have the [rack cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem and in application.rb:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. I see an error in the Chrome console which says

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/.... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.20:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

As per other suggestions, I have tried this:

```
config.middleware.insert_after Rails::Rack::Logger, Rack::Cors, :logger => Rails.logger do
```

but interestingly, there is nothing in the logs. I have also tried inserting the code into `config.ru` and in `development.rb` respectively.

I know the basic mechanics of CORS, but I don't understand what the issue here is.

Comment: touching your app wont change google settings. Google is rejecting the request

Comment: @apneadiving I've come to same conclusion myself (albeit after a long period of head scratching). What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: query the proper google service, ie the google webservices :)